# Complex PDF Generation Using Java

Tags: pdf-generation

I'm stuck with the PDF generation in my recent project. The project is to generate passenger details along with additional information. This report is generated by collecting information from different microservices and populate the data into the pdf. It's a kind of report. The design is as follows

[image]

There will be more fields are there with similar table of contents. Is anyone one have the idea about how to do this. I tried different pdf generation tools like

- jasperReports
- com.github.librepdf
- Dynamicreports

Anyone have the idea about how to do this, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you suggest any creative ways to layout a table with multiple cells and rows, where the first cell has four fields arranged in a unique pattern and the second cell has five fields with a different pattern?

Comment: any suggestions for commercial packages? @KJ

Comment: if the fields are pretty constrained, I'd just create an Acroform using whatever visual tool and then use a library to fill in the Acroforms with data and flatten to a regular PDF.

Comment: We used [FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) for that in the past. Your design is called stylesheet and after defining it, you can dynamically generate a PDF (or lots of other formats...)

Comment: And another question is why JasperReports didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this. I have used [pdfBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) to do this. PDFBox is a Java library that can be used to create, manipulate, and extract data from PDF documents. It provides various features to create complex PDF documents with tables, images, fonts, and more.

Comment: I don't really see how PDFBox is better suited for this than iText/OpenPDF which you have tried before. Probably you merely found example code better matching to your task using PDFBox than using iText/OpenPDF.

Comment: Good for you - PDFBox is a solid, maintained opensource PDF project...